# Magento COD Error

Tags: php, magento, checkout, fatal-error

When Customer place order with CODE payment method it show this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getTypeInstance() on a
>   non-object in
>   /home/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Abstract.php
>   on line 44

Any one can help please?

Comment: Show us the code where this error occurred.

Comment: <?php
abstract class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Abstract extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Retrive product
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        $product = parent::getProduct();
        if (is_null($product->getTypeInstance(true)->getStoreFilter($product))) {
            $product->getTypeInstance(true)->setStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore(), $product);
        }

        return $product;
    }
}